# Programmatically make app FULL SCREEN in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I know that an app can be made full screen by tag in the manifest of the activity `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` Is it possible to switch to full screen mode from within the app, programmatically?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

add two lines...

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Comment: Thanks Samir for your quick response, will check it out.

Comment: Perhaps, you could take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005746/enable-appearence-on-window-after-setflags-on-android-cordova and help me out?

Comment: but this code will restrict scrollview ... after this code scrollview will not work

Answer (score 15):

You can create new style and add

`<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>`

Or you can do it programmatically:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: these lines are restricting scrollview for scrolling.

Comment: doc of `addFlags()`: Convenience function to set the flag bits as specified in flags, as per {@link #setFlags}. It's just a call of `setFlags(flags, flags);` in fact.

Answer (score 10):

add this in Activity onCreate before setContentView:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // remove title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

and in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

Comment: Why add it in the manifest as well? and does this still work on newer devices?

Answer (score 3):

If you need a fullscreen immersive mode (for games, galleries, etc.), here is the solution I use and recommend.

The most efficient way is to set the SystemUIVisibility only when is needed:

1. In your onCreate()
2. With OnSystemUIChangeListener when the fullscreen mode is lost

public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

```
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private static final int UI_OPTIONS = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;        

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Step 1
    hideSystemUI();

    // Step 2
    getWindow().getDecorView()
               .setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View
               .OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                hideSystemUI();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void hideSystemUI() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) actionBar.hide();
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(UI_OPTIONS);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
// remove title
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                     setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

or

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

in onCreate()   method  write

> requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
>   this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);