# Hide Notification Bar in Custom Theme Android

Tags: android, fullscreen, android-notification-bar

I have designed a Custom Theme for my android application.
I want the application to go fullscreen but also display the TitleBar.
I want to hide/disable the NotificationBar but retain the TitleBar.
I tired this code. But this hides the TitleBar instead of the NotificationsBar.

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10803992/776244

Answer (score 1):

```
      requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Add this code to your Android Manifest.xml

Comment: I want to keep the title bar and disable the notification bar.