# Enable appearence on Window after setFlags on Android/Cordova

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing my first Cordova plugin as a means to learn Cordova better. I'm however stock and hope you guys can help with the last bits.

The source can be found at https://github.com/dotnetCarpenter/cordova-plugins/tree/master/FullscreenPlugin

The aim is to develop a full screen plugin which can toggle between states. As shown [here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803973/programmatically-make-app-full-screen-in-android#answer-10803992), it should only be three lines.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Which translated to Cordova would be:

```
Activity activity = this.cordova.getActivity();
activity.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
activity.getWindow()
 .setFlags(
 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
 );
activity.setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

`R.layout.main` gave me all kinds of trouble. Maybe because I'm missing something in my plugin.xml. I'm not sure.
Anyway, after finding a [post about toggling full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684440/android-exit-from-full-screen-mode#answer-13234388).
I figured I change the last line to:

```
activity.getCurrentFocus().requestLayout();
```

Unfortunately to no avail. I have tested a bunch of different setups, including `this.webView.requestLayout();`, but have reached my end.
I'm stuck!

I would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Cheers, Jon