# Bitmap.createScaledBitmap won't scale to screen size

Tags: android, bitmap

Got some problems with createScaledBitmap. It won't fit my screen size, i still have room to the left and right.

Why does this code

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;

    Resources res = getResources();

    Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.red);
    Bitmap overlay = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, width, height, false);
```

result in this screen:

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bitmap is actually larger in height than your `ImageView` because its the screen size and not the view's size which means the `ImageView` scale type is being enforced and scaling your bitmap down. Set the scale type on your view in XML or on in code to Matrix. Which will not perform any scaling because the Matrix is set to the identity matrix by default.

Comment: We've got a winner! fitXY also works for me. What would be the main difference between fitXY and matrix? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: "matrix" will not apply any scaling in this case. "fitxy" will scale it to fit the view. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in any activity to get the screen dimensions :

```
    public static int displayWidth,displayHeight;



    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    displayWidth = dm.widthPixels;
    displayHeight = dm.heightPixels;
```

and pass the displayWidth and height variables to

> Bitmap.createScaledBitmap

method

Comment: Thanks, but it results in the same behaviour. Both methods of getting the screen size result in 1920 x 1080 for height and width, and in both cases still the white bars on the side :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this to Decode the Bitmap :

Where imagefilepath is the path name of image,it will be in String covert that to File by using

`File photos= new File(imageFilePath);`
Where photo is the File name of the Image,Now you set your height and width according t your requirements.

```
Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(photo);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,150, 150, true);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);              
        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale++;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting a filepath for the image, even if I put in the root folder. But, I've checked Bitmapfactory.Options, and isn't that scaling to keep the correct aspect ratio?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe it's because you not consider action bar height

try this code

```
    //this for getting actionbar height
    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    int actionBarHeight = 0;
    if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true))
    {
        actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    ////////
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    //
    int height = size.y - actionBarHeight;

    Resources res = getResources();

    Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.red);
    Bitmap overlay = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, width, height, false);
```

Comment: Hi. I thought that might be the case, so i just switched the themo to have no titlebar. Still the same result though. I updated the image in the question. Thanks though :)

Comment: then try also hide title [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803973/programmatically-make-app-full-screen-in-android)

Comment: Ow, no the titlebar is gone (see picture). The "same result" I was talking about is the bitmap not scaling the width properly