# How can I do permanently fullScreen app on Java

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-fullscreen

I made the application full screen with the following code block. But when user scrolls from top to bottom, notification bar and nav bar appear. How can I completely prevent this?

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); // Tam ekran yap
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803973/programmatically-make-app-full-screen-in-android

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. Cannot find "R.layout.main". So I tried "R.layout.activity_main" and it didn't work.
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` @ALAEDDIN

Comment: Do you mean you want to completely prevent the user from closing or minimizing the app? That doesn't sound like something Android should allow.

Comment: I am developing a device. This device will be available to everyone. So I will not release apps for personal phones. I thought maybe there is a way. @Jorn

Comment: If you have full control over the device and OS, there's always the option of building a custom Android release from source

Answer (score 0):

You might have to change your Java class accordingly little bit.

If you want to remove status bar too then use this before setContentView(layout) in onCreateView method

```
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. I don't have a `setContentView(layout)`. Instead I have a `setContentView(binding.getRoot())`.

Answer (score 0):

Just Used these 2 lines of code inside onCreate

```
Window window = getWindow();
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window,false);
    
//Night mode off (Only used when you are off Night mode in apps)
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

Comment: Where exactly did you use it? When I added the code, I didn't get any results.